# Can you grant user edit permissions for uploaded content on DSpace 6.2?

Tags: dspace

Is it possible to grant permissions to a user to enable them to edit metadata or update attachments after uploading content on DSpace 6.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure a collection in which your submitters have (1)Add and (2)Write access to a collection.  This is not a standard option, so you must configure this from the Admin->Authorizations page.

[image: Collection Authorization Configuration]

Group Configuration
[image: Submitter Group Configuration]

The users in this group will have the ability to edit an item after submission.

[image: Item View from a Submitter Perspective]